# Login token required when calling this method or function

Tags: web-services, https, get

I am not familiar with webservices at all.
The third party company told me to use webservice and sent me the `https` link. I just need to provide parameters.

After I did that I got an error message:

[image]

So I used crm.zoho.com to generate temporary token.
It looks like that:

[image]

So now, where should I place this token? As a parameter?
Something like that?

```
https://servername/blabla/myfile.asmx/ExecuteDataSet?procedureName=MyProcName&parameters=300335&Token=7956838eab62585c2e334c4f348a00b6
```

It doesnt work if I pass the token as a parameter. Or maybe there is syntax errors.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before integration, i would suggest reading about token-based authentication method in web service / APIs.

This will provide you all possible ways to generate authentication token and how to use that token.

It all depends on the way end user/company has created that Web Service/API. Most of the time they provide an API/endpoint using which you can generate the token and use that token for other API/endpoint calls.

You also need to think of below points:-

- Is this token has an expiration date?
- If yes, you need to generate the token again

Note:- Some API/endpoint except token as part of header or query string. You can read the document from the provider and use it at right place.